# Rails: Adding items dynamically into Owl Carousel

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, owl-carousel

My rails app loads a list of objects to show in an Owl Carousel:

objects_controller.rb

```
class ObjectsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json, :js

  def index
    @objects = Object.first(5)
  end
```

index.html.erb:

```
 <div id="object_carousel" class="owl-carousel">
    <%= render 'objects_loop', objects: @objects %>
  </div>


  <div class="hidden">
    <%= link_to "get more objects", objects_path, remote: true, :id => "more-objects" %>
  </div>
```

objects_loop.rb:

```
<% objects.each_with_index do |event, index| %>
      <%= render 'object', object: object, index: index %>
<% end %>
```

Object partial:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 object" data-index="<%= index %>">
  <!-- stuff about the object -->
  <div class="button">Destroy Object</div>
</div>
```

I have JS to watch when the last object is reached, which then fetches new objects:

```
 $('.button').click(function(){
      var objectIndex = $(this).closest(".object").data("index")
      if (objectIndex === 4) {
        $("#more-objects").click();
      };
    });
```

And then an index.js.erb partial to re-render the objects_loop:

```
$("#object_carousel").html("<%= j render(partial: 'objects_loop', :locals => { :objects => @objects }) %>")
```

I can see in the HTML that the objects are actually being loaded properly in the DOM. But they are not visible... So I suspect something weird is happening with OwlCarousel.

How do I continue the carousel with the new objects? From a user's perspective, they shouldn't notice anything is happening.

Comment: Re-initialize the Owl Carousel in your index.js.erb?

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm not quite sure how to implement this. Tried owl.data('#object_carousel').reinit({ singleItem : true });  but I don't have access to the owl variable from my object.js asset file